# Google Analytics SDK v4 Tracking Campaigns Emailing No Data

Tags: android, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am trying to track Campaigns (emailing for example) with the Android SDK v4 but it's not working as we cannot see any data in our Google Analytics account.

We are trying to use the code below to send the data to Google Analytics:

URL we want to track:

```
URL SCHEME : scheme://www.example.com/commandes?utm_source=Mail_Invitation_Vente_ET&utm_medium=email&utm_term=ALL&utm_content=ALL&utm_campaign=TEST_CAMPAIGN
OR
URLs WEB:
http://www.example.com/commandes?utm_source=Mail_Invitation_Vente_ET&utm_medium=email&utm_term=ALL&utm_content=ALL&utm_campaign=TEST_CAMPAIGN

http://examplepetstore.com/index.html?utm_source=email&utm_medium=email_marketing&utm_campaign=summer&utm_content=email_variation_1 
(the documentation : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns)
```

Code for tracking :

```
Tracker tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).newTracker("UA-XXXXX");
tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
tracker.setScreenName("SCREEN/ android");
tracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().setCampaignParamsFromUrl(URL_TO_TRACK).build());
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).dispatchLocalHits();
```

We also tried this:

```
HashMap<String, String> campaignMap = new HashMap<>(3);
campaignMap.put("utm_source", SOURCE_TO_TRACK);
campaignMap.put("utm_medium", MEDIUM_TO_TRACK);
campaignMap.put("utm_campaign", CAMPAIGN_TO_TRACK);
tracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().setAll(campaignMap).build());
```

We want to track a click on a specific link through URL SCHEME (protocol or HTTP URL).

Could you tell us if we did something wrong in my code?

SDK version : play-services:7.5.0
I am using Google Analytics v4.

Comment: Can anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Google play services analytics `9.0.1` is out now.

Answer (score 0):

### Follow following way- In Your Splash Screen Activity Or MainActivity You Need to Define

```
public static GoogleAnalytics analytics;

public static Tracker tracker;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);
        tracker = analytics.newTracker("UA-XXXXX-0");
        tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
        tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
        tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
String campaignData = "http://examplepetstore.com/index.html?utm_source=email&utm_medium=email_marketing&utm_campaign=summer&utm_content=email_variation_1 ";

        tracker.setReferrer(campaignData);

        tracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
                .setCampaignParamsFromUrl(campaignData)
                .build());



}
```

**AndroidMainfest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxxxxxx"
    android:versionCode="11"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="23"
        android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

 <application
 <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <!--
            Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
            installation campaign reporting
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
       -->

        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**App level build.gradel**

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':Volley')
    compile project(':Volley')

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    //apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

}

android {

    //compileSdkVersion 20
    //buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxxx"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

**Project level build.gradel**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        //mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }
}
```